# Join multiple lazy sequences of strings in Clojure

Tags: string, clojure, concatenation, lazy-sequences

I have several strings:

```
(def a "some random string")
(def b "this is a text")
```

Now i want to concatenate parts of them to create a string "some text". Unfortunately both of the strings below didn't work.

```
(clojure.string/join " " [(take 4 a) (take-last 4 b)])
(str (take 4 a) " " (take-last 4 b))
```

It's because functions `take` and `take-last` return lazy sequences. The question is: what is the proper way to concatenate multiple lazy sequences of strings and return one string?

**Edit:** I found one solution - `(apply str (concat (take 4 a) " " (take-last 4 a)))` - but is it the most correct way?

Comment: The way in your *Edit* looks good to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using sequence functions to slice the input strings, you might want to use the *much* more efficient `subs` (for substring; note there's a GC-related caveat about it, see below):

```
(subs "asdf" 1 2)
; => "s"

;; a and b as in the question text
(clojure.string/join " " [(subs a 0 4) (subs b (- (count b) 4))])
; => "some text"
```

The aforementioned caveat is that as long as the `"s"` returned in the first example here remains ineligible for garbage collection, so does the original `"asdf"` (since `subs` returns a "view" onto the input `String` without allocating fresh storage -- this is the behaviour of Java's `substring` method which `subs` wraps). This is not a problem if you immediately hand the `"s"` off to `subs` and retain no other reference to it, since `join` will discard it after pulling the characters.

If you do end up working with lazy sequences of characters after all, there's nothing to be done but to use something like `(map (partial apply str) [...your vector here...])` to turn the inputs to `clojure.string/join` into strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and yes becoz of the laziness the result of your code is not proper.

```
(str (apply str (take 4 a)) " " (apply str (take-last 4 b)))
```

Comment: The problem isn't so much laziness. But that calling toString on a LazySeq of characters doesn't return a string consisting of the characters in that seq. The OP would have a similar problem with a vector of characters or a list of characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
(str/join " " (map (fn [f col] (f col))
               [first last]
               (map #(str/split % #" ") [a b])))
```